# Is there a way to force SortOrder on Related Data in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Assuming that I have an EF Code-First implementation with the following simplified scenario:

```
public class Form{
    [key]
    int FormID {get;set;}
    int Name {get;set;}

    public virtual ICollection<FormAndQuestionMapping> FormQuestionMappings
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class FormAndQuestionMapping{
    [ForeginKey]
    int FormID {get;set;}

    [ForeginKey]
    int QuestionID {get;set;}

    int SortOrder {get; set;}

    public virtual Form Form { get; set; }
    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
}
```

FormAndQuestionMapping data:

```
 FormID | QuestionID | SortOrder
   1    |     1      |     5
   1    |     2      |     20
   1    |     3      |     10
   1    |     4      |     15
```

Is there a way to force FormQuestionMappings to be loaded by their SortOrder and not by their default location?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.
Entity Framework accepts all collections, that implements ICollection interface. So, you can use your own collection, that is sorded in any way you want.
EF materialize collections via Add method calls on ICollection interface. So, something like this should work:

```
public class Form
{
    private ICollection<FormAndQuestionMapping> _formQuestionMappings;

    public Form()
    {
        _formQuestionMappings = new SortedSet<FormAndQuestionMapping>(new Comparer());
    }

    private class Comparer : IComparer<FormAndQuestionMapping>
    {
        public int Compare(FormAndQuestionMapping x, FormAndQuestionMapping y)
        {
            return x.SortOrder - y.SortOrder;
        }
    }

    [key]
    int FormID { get; set; }
    int Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<FormAndQuestionMapping> FormQuestionMappings
    {
        get { return _formQuestionMappings; }
        set { _formQuestionMappings = value; }
    }
}

public class FormAndQuestionMapping
{
    [ForeginKey]
    int FormID { get; set; }

    [ForeginKey]
    int QuestionID { get; set; }

    public int SortOrder { get; set; }

    public virtual Form Form { get; set; }
    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This actually works and it may be sufficient. Note however that it's purely client-side. If `FormQuestionMappings` is used in a projection (`select new { ... }`), explicit sorting is still necessary.

Comment: @GertArnold yes, I agree. I don't know the whole problem, but if we assume that `Form` is a root domain entity, and you can't query `FormAndQuestionMapping` directly, this solution is quite suitable, I think.

Comment: @kob490 have you checked it?

Comment: First thing on my todos tomorrow. got a question though. is there an alternative to  SortedSet that i can use that supports a simpler lambda instead of Comparer. such as _formQuestionMappings = new SortedSet<FormAndQuestionMapping>(m => m.SortOrder)?

Comment: @kob490 no, I don't know such collections. SortedSet is the best for this task, I know