# Can I mapping an ordered list in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

I want to have List in my entity where T is another entity. The idea is that the table for T would have a column which gets automatically updated which index of the list. From what I have read it seems EF didn't support it the past but am hoping that this can be done in the current version. I would have thought this is a pretty common requirement. If it is not supported directly what are some good workarounds.

Comment: check my answer on similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43926462/is-there-a-way-to-force-sortorder-on-related-data-in-entity-framework/43932802#43932802

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to force SortOrder on Related Data in Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43926462/is-there-a-way-to-force-sortorder-on-related-data-in-entity-framework)